# Copy the attributes in XSLT

Tags: xslt, msxsl

Now I have an XML file as below:

```
<DM Name="A DM"> 
  <DV  id="SQL:Select something from db" Name="DV 1"> 
    <Sample aid="SQL:Select something from db" /> 
  </DV> 
  <DV  id="SQL:Select something from db" Name="DV 2"> 
    <Sample aid="SQL:Select something from db" name ="DC"> 
      good 
    </Sample> 
  </DV> 
</DM>
```

I want to use an XSLT to transform it, there is a parameter in this tamplet to determine which DV should be transformed: if the parameter($dvIndex = 0), then just keep all the elements and attributes, just transform the attriform the attritributes with the value started with "SQL:", if ($dvindext > 0), just transform the specific DV,(remove other DV). Now I write the XSLT as below, but it miss the DM's attributes, I don't know how to copy DM's attributes. I donot know if there is better solution. XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
    xmlns:user="urn:my-scripts"
>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <msxsl:script language="C#" implements-prefix="user">
    <![CDATA[
     public string UpperCase(string value){
      return value.ToUpper();
     }
      ]]>
  </msxsl:script>

  <xsl:param name="dvIndex" select="2" />

  <xsl:template match="DM" >
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$dvIndex > 0">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="DV[$dvIndex]"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
          </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!--[starts-with(translate(substring(.,1,4),'SQL:','sql:'),'sql:')]-->
  <xsl:template match="@*[user:UpperCase(substring(.,1,4))='SQL:']">
    <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
      <xsl:value-of select="'parsedSQL'"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

this question is also related to my question 2# ([How to only convert an XML file's attribute using XSLT, and leave the other content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289926/how-to-only-convert-an-xml-files-attribute-using-xslt-and-leave-the-other-conte))

Thanks very much!

Comment: Please add to your post some examples of the desired output.

Comment: Try selecting "@*|DV[$dvIndex]" instead. Does that fix it?

Answer (score 1):

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:param name="dvIndex" select="2" />
    <xsl:template match="DM" >
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|DV[$dvIndex]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@*[starts-with(translate(substring(.,1,4),'SQL:','sql:'),'sql:')]">
        <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="'parsedSQL'"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result:

```
<DM Name="A DM">
<DV id="parsedSQL" Name="DV 2">
<Sample aid="parsedSQL" name="DC">
      good
    </Sample>
</DV>
</DM>
```

With param `dvIndex` in `0`:

```
<DM Name="A DM"></DM>
```

**Note**: Avoid scripting: it's not standar, it'll force to load script engine every time is used.

**EDIT**: If you want to process every `DV` when $dvIndex is 0, then this stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:param name="dvIndex" select="2" />
    <xsl:template match="DM" >
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|DV[$dvIndex]|DV[not($dvIndex)]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@*[starts-with(translate(substring(.,1,4),'SQL:','sql:'),'sql:')]">
        <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="'parsedSQL'"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With $dvIndex is 0, output:

```
<DM Name="A DM">
<DV id="parsedSQL" Name="DV 1">
<Sample aid="parsedSQL"></Sample>
</DV>
<DV id="parsedSQL" Name="DV 2">
<Sample aid="parsedSQL" name="DC">
      good
    </Sample>
</DV>
</DM>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following probably does what you need. Note the additional `<xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />` to copy the attributes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
    xmlns:user="urn:my-scripts">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <msxsl:script language="C#" implements-prefix="user">
    <![CDATA[
     public string UpperCase(string value){
      return value.ToUpper();
     } ]]>
  </msxsl:script>

  <xsl:param name="dvIndex" select="0" />

  <xsl:template match="DM" >
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$dvIndex > 0">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="DV[$dvIndex]"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="DV"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!--[starts-with(translate(substring(.,1,4),'SQL:','sql:'),'sql:')]-->
  <xsl:template match="@*[user:UpperCase(substring(.,1,4))='SQL:']">
    <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
      <xsl:value-of select="'parsedSQL'"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```